# ggplot failing to plot the correct color

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

ggplot2 seems to have gone haywire in my machine. No matter what color I specify, it seems to print the lines in red! For example, the following code also prints the plot in red (image attached).

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(Sys.Date(), len=100, by="1 day")[sample(100, 50)],
  price = runif(50)
)
df <- df[order(df$date), ]

dt <- qplot(date, price, data=df, geom="line", color="blue")
dt
```

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace colour = "blue" with this instead:

```
colour = I("blue")
```

---

As @joran rightly mentions, it's better to do it this way instead:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(date, price)) + geom_line(color="blue")
```

Comment: Indeed, this is one of the many reasons why I think `qplot` is just confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: yeah i think the idea is to add args to the geom objects explicitly by separating it.. i started using qplot.. and didn't realize what was being inferred alot of times..

Comment: I'm getting this with ggplot, too (not qplot), and 'size' still isn't working, no matter what I do.

Comment: @Sophologist I worked on this problem by specifying the colour argument outside of the aes argument e.g. `geom_line(aes(y = data ), colour = "blue")` instead of `geom_line(aes(y = data, color = "blue"))`